# Remote run server error

Tags: tomcat, ant

```
<sshexec 
    host="199.3.13.102" 
    username="${username}" 
    password="${password}" 
    trust="true" 
    timeout="10000"
    commandResource="run.txt"
/>
```

run.txt:

```
#!/bin/sh   

cd /usr/java/apache-tomcat-6.0.16/bin;pwd; 


sh /usr/java/apache-tomcat-6.0.16/bin/startup.sh;ps -ef|grep tomcat 


ps -ef|grep tomcat
```

And the result:

```
[sshexec] Connecting to 199.3.13.102:22
[sshexec] cmd : #!/bin/sh 
[sshexec] cmd :
[sshexec] cmd : cd /usr/java/apache-tomcat-6.0.16/bin;pwd; 
[sshexec] /usr/java/apache-tomcat-6.0.16/bin 
[sshexec] cmd : 
[sshexec] cmd :
[sshexec] cmd : sh /usr/java/apache-tomcat-6.0.16/bin/startup.sh;ps -ef|grep tomcat 
[sshexec] root     30459 30382  0 13:01 ?        00:00:00 bash -c sh /usr/java/apache-tomcat-6.0.16/bin/startup.sh;ps -ef|grep tomcat
[sshexec] root     30490     1  0 13:01 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util. 
logging.config.file=/usr/java/apache-tomcat-6.0.16/conf/logging.properties -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/java/apache-tomcat-6.0.16/endorsed -classpath :/usr/java/apache-tomcat-6.0.16/bin/bootstrap.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/java/apache-tomcat-6.0.16 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/java/apache-tomcat-6.0.16 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/java/apache-tomcat-6.0.16/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start 
[sshexec] root     30492 30459  0 13:01 ?        00:00:00 grep tomcat 
[sshexec] root     30497 30490  0 13:01 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/java/apache-tomcat-6.0.16/conf/logging.properties -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/java/apache-tomcat-6.0.16/endorsed -classpath :/usr/jav 
[sshexec] a/apache-tomcat-6.0.16/bin/bootstrap.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/java/apache-tomcat-6.0.16 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/java/apache-tomcat-6.0.16 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/java/apache-tomcat-6.0.16/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start 
[sshexec] cmd : 
[sshexec] cmd :
[sshexec] cmd : ps -ef|grep tomcat
[sshexec] root     30643 30382  0 13:01 ?        00:00:00 bash -c ps -ef|grep tomcat
[sshexec] root     30659 30643  0 13:01 ?        00:00:00 grep tomcat 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL 
Total time: 5 seconds
```

What's going on?
And the same as all scripts.
It does actually executed.
But ... I don't know why!

Ant version:
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010

Comment: Just to be clear, the issue is that the remote process starts, then exits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you execute startup.sh in a new shell (`sh startup.sh`)?

It may be that necessary environment variables (e.g. JAVA_HOME, CATALINA_HOME) which are defined in your login environment are missing when you execute in that new shell.

Consider executing startup.sh directly. Alternatively, you could try `sh -l` to execute in a login shell.